Fbx file viewer in outsystems
I am working in outsystems reactive web application. I want to upload file in outsystems upload widget and need to preview that fbx file in that application itself using autodesk. I had seen article of your team for that implementation
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/outsystems-integration
But it is for traditional web application, i need for reactive web application. Please help me to do that.
This is what my requirement is
I am new to outsystems. I am learning on my self. If anyone share me oml, it will be helpful. Please help me guys.

I'm not familiar with autodesk, but at first glance I don't see anything in the tutorial that you couldn't do in reactive. What is the problem you having in your reactive application?
